# how to resolve security issues in windows service?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, windows-services

```
Public Sub New()

    MyBase.New()

    InitializeComponent()

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\himanshu vaishnav\\Desktop\\DataSync(till download)\\DataSync\\bin\\Debug\\DataSync")

    If Not System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MySource") Then
        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("MySource", "MyNewLog")
    End If
    EventLog1.Source = "MySource"
    EventLog1.Log = "MyNewLog"

End Sub
```

in if condition i am getting security issues for "MySource". it is saying "The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security."

what to do??

Comment: VB does not require you to escape the path separator. `"C:\Users\himanshu vaishnav\Desktop\...` but that should be gotten from `Environment.GetFolderPath`

Comment: You should read the "Remarks" section of [EventLog.CreateEventSource Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zbwd3s3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Reading the documentation should not be a last resort ;)

Comment: @porkchop its standard example given by msdn website. except process.start method . i wasn't trying to read any security logs ,just trying to run that code and to understand the windows service. n trying to invoke any application from windows service. i just saw an example over the internet for that method n i was just trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Const _logName As String = "Application" ' this refers to the application event log
Private Const _appName As String = "myApp"

Friend Sub addEvent(ByVal _eventID As Integer, ByVal _strMessage As String)
    Try
        Try : EventLog.CreateEventSource(_appName, _logName) : Catch ex As Exception : End Try
        Using EL As New EventLog
            EL.Source = _appName
            EL.WriteEntry(_strMessage, EventLogEntryType.Information, _eventID)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' ... ignore (probably do something else instead)
    End Try
End Sub
```

i suppose as a note: standard users are unable create new event sources, nor can they read the security log, therefore:

`.SourceExists(_appName)` will always throw an exception as a standard user.

`.CreateEventSource()` will return an exception if the source does not exist as a standard user.

in order to create the event log `.Source` for the first time, you must be running elevated.

you could test for `My.User.IsInRole(ApplicationServices.BuiltInRole.Administrator)`, the problem is, that won't catch all the other exceptions for you unless you test for them as well, or rule them out completely, including: mismatched/invalid/too long - log/application names, security permissions, custom user permissions, etc... you can't always guarantee someone else working on the project will be aware of all those limitations. would require a lot of checks. more information on that here:

[EventLog Class (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.eventlog) - explains most of these security consideration.

[EventLog.CreateEventSource Method (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zbwd3s3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - explains most of the exceptions that can arise.

edit: if you plan to write lots of events to the log, you should refactor the code to declare `EL` a member variable of the Class/Object, and properly `.Close()` it when the applications terminates, Instead of using the `Using` statement.

Comment: @HimanshuAgrawat sorry, fixed it. i wrote it up in the window and never tested it. includes a more thorough explanation. also, you may consider changing the title of the question to something like: "SecurityException when writing to the EventLog".

Comment: @HimanshuAgrawat if you're doing this as a service, and can't run under a different user context, or first run, then you will need to create the source manually or use `EventLogInstaller` Class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.eventloginstaller, `ServiceInstaller` Class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and create a Setup Project for your service: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317421 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx although i haven't looked into it.